# Angular code not seeing controller and items

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to angular an trying to create and MVC project with angular.
I have create an about.js file and this is the code inside it:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TecknologiesController', function () {
        this.text = tech;
    });
    var tech = {
        name: 'Progamming',
        csharp: 'C#',
        asp: 'ASP .NET',
        xaml:'XAML',
        java: 'java',
        sql: 'SQL',
        plsql: 'PL/SQL',
        xml: 'XML',
        webs: 'Web Services'
    }
})();
```

I have added my script tags to the body of _layout.cshtml file like so:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="About.js"></script>
```

In my About.cshtml file i have this code to show one of the tech items in my about.js
this is my code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TecknologiesController as tech">
    <div>{{tech.text.name}}</div>
</div>
```

But this is not working for me. it prints out the **{{tech.text.name}}** as text. 
Am i adding the script tags wrong or what?
it is working fine here in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pYh89/1/

Comment: Do you have any other script errors in the page ? **The code is working fine in the jsfiddle your provided !!!!!**

Comment: Have been looking at script errors. and you were right.. My script tag definition didnt go through. I corrected my script tag and everything is now working.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-controller="TecknologiesController as tech" makes 'tech' point to this.

I think what you want is:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TecknologiesController', function () {
        this.tech = tech;
    });
    var tech = {
        name: 'Progamming',
        csharp: 'C#',
        asp: 'ASP .NET',
        xaml:'XAML',
        java: 'java',
        sql: 'SQL',
        plsql: 'PL/SQL',
        xml: 'XML',
        webs: 'Web Services'
    }
})();
```

And your HTML:

```
<div>{{tech.tech.name}}</div>
```

It really would be better if var tech = ... was declared and assigned before you use it.

You could also to this:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TecknologiesController', function () {
        var tech = this;
        tech.name = 'Programming;
        tech.csharp = 'C#';
        // etc ...
    });
})();
```

which would allow you to access name more directly

```
<div>{{tech.name}}</div>
```

But since I don't know what you are really trying to do, that's the best I can answer at this point.

You main issue, I think is that you don't understand that this is what tech points to.